# После подключения сайта к Cloudflare открывается чужая страница

Tags: хостинг, dns, домен

Такая ситуация у меня не впервые, знаю что когда сменятся dns всё наладится и будет открываться свой сайт. Но всё таки интересно, почему когда меняешь хостера и на сайте cloudflare прописываешь новые настройки DNS нового хостера, а на старом удаляешь сайт. То вместо своего сайта открывается сайт как на картинке. От куда он берется? Но стоит подождать, DNS сменится и заработает свой сайт. Не знаю, не ужели только у меня такое? В поиске ничего не нашёл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: За что минус то поставили? У меня тут пол дня уже место своего сайта реклама какой-то веб студии открывается, а вы минусы ставите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю что это заглушка хостинга, она, обычно, показывается пользователям когда сайт на хостинге отсутствует или только создан.

Можете просто расположить в директории с сайтом index.html с собственной заглушкой, это решит Вашу проблему.